# Too long processing time for a 3-d plot

Tags: python-3.x, time, 3d

I am comparatively new to python, so I am not able to assess if there is something wrong with my code or is the process taking too long to complete or anything else.

I wrote a code for plotting a large dataset (3d array) in a 3d plot, but my PC takes forever to complete (or not complete). I have been waiting for about one hour for it to complete nearly.

```py
a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([Ensemble_test,df['RF'],y])).transpose()
a   # is a dataset with dimentions 335516 rows × 3 columns
### All the 3 rows are numbers
Output:
    0           1            2
0   172.981614  130.624674  -42.356940
1   189.851754  139.632304  -50.219450

## I tried plotting using following
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df=a.unstack().reset_index()
df.columns=["X","Y","Z"]

df['X']=pd.Categorical(df['X'])
df['X']=df['X'].cat.codes

# Make the plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
im =  ax.plot_trisurf(df['Y'], df['X'], df['Z'], cmap='Spectral', linewidth=0.001, vmax = 30,
                      vmin = -30, antialiased=True)
ax.view_init(40,20)
#fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, fraction = 0.023)

ax.set_ylabel('RD')
ax.set_zlabel('Difference')
ax.set_xlabel('Ensemble')
```

I wanted to have a 3-d plot but the process takes too long. I don't know what the problem is.

Any other alternatives/suggestions for 3-d plotting are also welcome.

[My PC is 8th gen 'i7' with '16 GB' RAM]

Comment: Have you tried it with a small data points sample?

Comment: I deleted the `processing` tag since that tag is about the programming language called [Processing](https://processing.org/). Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque........Yes it worked fine before.